# My web application stop working after JSESSIONID appear in URL

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, tomcat7, session-cookies

I have a web application running in Apache Tomcat 7 and using Struts2.
My login system is made by putting a User object in a session:

( bypassing "if" and "try" to be clear..)

```
UserService es = new UserService();
User user = es.login(username, password);
ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put("loggedUser", user);
```

And then, I try to get a User object from that session in a Interceptor. If ok, then someone is logged. If not, go to login page by returning "notLogged" that will be catch by Struts2 global-results in struts.xml :

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) {
    User loggedUser = (User)invocation.getInvocationContext().getSession().get("loggedUser");
    if (loggedUser == null) {
        return "notLogged";
    }
    try {
        return invocation.invoke();
    } catch ( Exception ignored ) {
        return "notLogged";
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```xml
<global-results>
    <result name="notLogged">/index.jsp</result> 
</global-results>
```

All was very well, until the server admin do some maintenance and the "jsessionid" starts to appear in URL. After this, I can't navigate my system anymore (until I copy and paste this ID in every URL I want to go. no way to form action destinations). I still be able to login and I see the User object still be catching, but I can't go to any destination without this ID.

I tried this: https://fralef.me/tomcat-disable-jsessionid-in-url.html, and put `COOKIE` in `tracking-mode` tag in my web.xml but the things goes worst because now I can't do even a login.

What was happened, what can I do to solve this and put my system back to work?

Comment: Your browser started to reject cookies, for some reason (or some network infrastructure change removed the cookie from the responses or requests). It's possible to avoid cookies, but then ALL URLs must be properly encoded (using the <c:url> tag, for example). Check where the cookie disappears. Ask the server admin what he did to cause that problem.

Comment: Sorry. Is not the case. I said this starts after some server changes by an admin. And how can every browser I try starts to reject cookies? Anywhere. Some conspiration? Is not in the browser. I not have seen this ID in URL before.

Comment: As I know, the only change is the server acces redirection from http://eic.cefet-rj.br/sagitarii to http://eic.cefet-rj.br/rukbat/app/sagitarii. This is an external access redirecting to an internal network ( <host_ip>:<port>\sagitarii )

Comment: may have something to do with cookie path. try changing sessionCookiePath

Comment: @bayou.io : Many thanks. solved by puting `<Context sessionCookiePath="/">` in server context.xml. Please put it as an answer to allow me to accept.

Comment: @MagnoC please you too answer yourself with the solution that have worked for you, because people often don't look at comments

Comment: @Andrea Ligios : what ??

Comment: I've seen from your comment on the answer that you've got later what I was suggesting (answering your own question, without accepting the answer, just because an answer is read, a comment often is not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently caused by cookie path mismatch.

Browser will only send back the cookie if the request URL path matches the cookie path, e.g.

```
 cookie path :  /abc
request path:   /abc/xyz   // match
request path:   /xyz       // no match
```

By default, Tomcat set the session cookie path as the web app path, so that the cookie will not be sent to other web apps. However, in your case, the middleware changes the request URL path, therefore the browser observes a different path, causing cookie path mismatch.

In most cases, I'd recommend to set cookie path to "/", so that it matches all requests to the server (assuming there's only one app on Tomcat)

```
// context.xml
<Context sessionCookiePath="/">
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks by the explanation. Know the cause is much better to understand the error rather than just copy and past.

Comment: @bayou.io if you set `/` as cookie path , JSESSIONIDs will overlap themselves between applications, won't they ?

Comment: @bayou.io : As Andrea Ligios said, Please edit your answer to explicitly refer to `<Context sessionCookiePath="/">` in `context.xml` solution ( as I comment my question ). I'm too lazy to answer myself and want to accept yours because the explanation.

Comment: @AndreaLigios - absolutely. However, on most production servers, there is only one app anyway. You could also use different cookie names for different apps. In any case, cookie path is a very poor way of [isolating](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-8.5) cookies; it is much [trickier](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/javadoc/bayou/http/Cookie.html#path) than one would expect;  and it causes lots of headaches. That's why I'd rather set it to `/` by default and effectively forget about the cookie path feature.

Comment: In these days, domains are so cheap, we should always use a different domain for a new app. Or use a free subdomain. [Cookie Domain](http://bayou.io/draft/cookie.domain.html) is good at isolating cookies. In the old days when Servlet was designed, there might be legit reasons to use path to separate apps; but that is highly unusual today.

Comment: I agree, but sometimes you can't just change the domain... also consider that cookies are for location, not server... I've seen multiple servers (each one with different apps) mounted under the same (institutional, eg the site of a city, or a country) location. I've also seen session overlapping due to "/" on path :D so I guess it deserved a mention in your answer (that you've already put ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios what's the problem if JSESSIONIDs overlap between applications deployed in the same container? Even if the cookie values are the same, the applications would still get different session objects in the server. Unless you are using the JSESSIONID to make queries to a back-end database. Is this your case?

Comment: The first session gets invalidated